# Custom IOptions map path

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

I currently have a Json config file that looks something like this :

```
{
    "MySettings" " {
         "SomeSetting" : "SomeValue"
    }
}
```

In the perfect world, I would have a class that matches that same structure. But, I need to map it to a class that would look something like this :

```
public class MySettingsUpdated
{
    public string MyRenamedSetting {get;set;}
}
```

I am already using a custom ConfigurationProvider to get data from a configuration file (for various reasons), and I -could- create the data in the expected path in there, but it would make my life much easier if I could decorate the new class with some type of attribute in order to specify where the data needs to come from.

Any way to do this?

Comment: you can configure the options like  `services.Configure<MySettingsUpdated>(options =>
            {
                options.MyRenamedSetting = this.Configuration["MySettings:SomeSetting"];
            });` at startup.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static string data = @"
    {
      ""class"": {
        ""property"" :  ""some string!""
      }
    }";

    class DTO
    {
        [JsonProperty("class")]
        public Data Property { get; set; }
    }

    class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("property")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTO>(data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This, however, did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Bind()` method exposed on the `IConfigurationSection` interface.

In a class it could look like

```
public class SomeClassDoingWork
{
    private MyConfigClass MyConf = new MyConfigClass();

    public SomeClassDoingWork(IConfiguration config)
    {
        config.GetSection("MySettings").Bind(MyConf);
    }
}
```